# Empty Region - Android XML Layout and Mac OS X 10.7

Tags: android, eclipse, android-layout

I've been using the ADT release from developers.android.com that comes with SDK and Eclipse in one package. I have some code that gives me a Empty Region exception upon drawing the XML file in the graphical layout tab.

> Exception raised during rendering: Empty region! Exception details are
>   logged in Window > Show View > Error Log
>
> java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Empty region!
>       at javax.imageio.ImageReader.computeRegions(ImageReader.java:2689)
>       at com.sun.imageio.plugins.wbmp.WBMPImageReader.read(WBMPImageReader.java:184)
>       at javax.imageio.ImageIO.read(ImageIO.java:1422)
>       at javax.imageio.ImageIO.read(ImageIO.java:1282)
>       at android.graphics.Bitmap_Delegate.createBitmap(Bitmap_Delegate.java:96)
>       at com.android.layoutlib.bridge.impl.ResourceHelper.getDrawable(ResourceHelper.java:233)
>       at com.android.layoutlib.bridge.bars.CustomBar.loadIcon(CustomBar.java:196)
>       at com.android.layoutlib.bridge.bars.CustomBar.loadIconById(CustomBar.java:188)
>       at com.android.layoutlib.bridge.bars.CustomBar.loadIconById(CustomBar.java:155)
>       at com.android.layoutlib.bridge.bars.FakeActionBar.(FakeActionBar.java:38)

This came on suddenly and shows a null pointer exception on Windows version of eclipse with the SDK.

I've checked for all images, as someone somewhere said something about corrupted images. Programs can view them just fine. I've fixed the project settings and reloaded eclipse, failed to resolve.

> ```
>     <com.demortes.controller.DualJoystickView
>             android:id="@+id/dualjoystickView"
>             android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
>             android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="175dp"
>             android:layout_marginLeft="10dp" android:layout_marginRight="10dp"/>
> ```
>
> ```
>                     <Button
>                         android:id="@+id/button_A"
>                         android:layout_width="90dp"
>                         android:text="@string/a_button"
>                         android:textSize="24sp"
>                         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
>                         android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
>                         android:layout_marginRight="10dp" />
>
>                     <Button
>                         android:id="@+id/button_B"
>                         android:text="@string/b_button"
>                         android:textSize="24sp"
>                         android:layout_width="90dp"
>                         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
>                         android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal" />
>
>
>             </LinearLayout>
>
>     <LinearLayout
>             android:layout_width="wrap_content"
>             android:layout_height="wrap_content"
>             android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal" >
>
>             <Button
>                 android:id="@+id/button_Y"
>                 android:text="@string/y_button"
>                 android:textSize="24sp"
>                 android:layout_width="90dp"
>                 android:layout_height="wrap_content"
>                 android:layout_marginRight="10dp" />
>
>             <Button
>                 android:id="@+id/button_X"
>                 android:text="@string/x_button"
>                 android:textSize="24sp"
>                 android:layout_width="90dp"
>                 android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
>
>
>             </LinearLayout>
> ```

There's my XML file.

Now here's where it gets weird. When I switch the API from 17 to 8 in the graphical layout tab, it draws it... but incorrectly. It's completely strange to me.

Any insight you can think of is greatly appreciated! TIA.

Comment: I am facing the same problem, every layout shows this error. Did you find the answer?

Comment: I have not unfortunately. I've put the android stuff on hold as of right now or worked around it.

Answer (score 1):

check Manifest.xml like this

```
 <application
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:icon="@drawable/logo"/>
```

make sure  "drawable_hdpi" "drawable_ldpi" "drawable_mdpi" have file logo.png and the image resolution is correct.

Comment: This is fairly old, I don't even know if I'm having the issue anymore. Not entirely sure as the Android app project was put on the backburner. I'll check at work, and get back to you.